# Why edit text width not decreasing?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place 3 edit text box in a row, the first one remains in Wrap_content and other 2 are decreasing to the specific size. Why this so, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance here in my xml code

```
 <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/editText6"
                  android:layout_width="80dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:ems="10" /> 

              <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/editText7"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:ems="10" />

               <EditText
                  android:id="@+id/editText8"
                  android:layout_width="80dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:ems="10" />

        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

Try giving each EditText an equal weight and set width as 0dp.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: You want each editText to have the same size in the table row ?

Comment: yes ThankQ. It worked 4 me. Take some flowers on behalf of me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21680/discussion-between-bamadeva-and-androider)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editText6"
              android:layout_width="80dp"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:ems="10" /> 

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editText7"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:ems="10" />

           <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editText8"
              android:layout_width="80dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:ems="10" />

    </TableRow>
```